# separating retrofit 2 calls away from activities and fragments. Am I doing correctly?

Tags: android, rest, android-activity, retrofit2

I have a retrofit function for which i make call from various activities and fragments, which produces same output type. for simple example

```
retrofitService.fetchData().enqueue(new Callback<MyData>{})
```

since i am going to call the same function from different activities i created a separate common call back interface

```
interface OnDataFetch(){
// where mydata holds the response body on success
// msg is response.ErrorBody when the response code is not 200 
// resonseType = 0 for success
// responseType = 1 for response code other than 200
// reponstType = 1 for on failure
public void dataFetched(Data mydata,ErrorMsg msg, int responseType);
}
```

now on on response and on failure i call the dataFetched();

```
onSuccess(.....){

response.isSuccessful(){
 responsetType = 0;
 Data mydata = response.body();
}else{
 //when response code is not 200 we get error msg from server
 responstType = 1;
 mydata = null;
 ErrorMsg msg = Gson.from(response.ErrorBody(),ErrorMsg);
}
  dataFetched(mydata,msg,responseType);
}


onFailure(....){
 responseType = 2;
 dataFetched(null,null,responseType);
}
```

now all those activities which require mydata implements the dataFetched interface. Hence i am separating retrofit logics into separate class. Is this the right way to simplify activities with REST API calls or is there some there better way to do the same. Later may be i will store those response to sql database, take that also into consideration while answering thanks(Don't care about syntax).